# Dialog box is not closing

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I am working on displaying a dropdown list in a dialog box using [react-native-modals](https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-modals). After selecting an item from the dropdown list, the dialog box is closing automatically and displays data of the selected item on a screen but some items in a dropdown list don't have their respective data. For these items, I apply a condition to select another item in the list but after applying a condition in a program, a dialog box is not closing, it keeps remain on the screen with selected item's data in the background.

Here is my code

```js
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: true
    }
  }

_onCityChange = city => {
    const { uid, date } = this.props;
    this.setState({
        visible: false
      });
      this.props.citiesShow({ uid, city, date })
  }

render() {
  console.log(this.props);
    let dropdownData = () => {
      let cities = this.props.cities;
      let count = Object.keys(cities).length;
      let cityList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cityList.push({ value: cities[i].city });
      }
      return cityList;
    }
    const dropdownCity = dropdownData();

if ((this.props.cityName.length > 0) && (this.props.cityData == '')) //THIS IS CONDITION
    {
      return (
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>No data for this location yet.</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Select another city.</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      );
    }
    else{
      return (
        <View>

          <View>
            <Dialog
              visible={this.state.visible}
              dialogAnimation={new SlideAnimation({ slideFrom: 'bottom' })}
              dialogStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}>
              <DialogContent>
                <View>
                  <Dropdown
                    label='Select your city..'
                    labelFontSize={14}
                    selectedItemColor={'black'}
                    baseColor={'black'}
                    style={{ fontSize: 22, fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                    containerStyle={{ width: 300, height: 83 }}
                    data={dropdownCity}
                    onChangeText={this._onCityChange} />
                </View>
              </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
          </View>


          <FlatList
            data={this.props.prayer}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={this.renderItem} />

        </View>
      );
  }
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    mainData: state.city.main,
    uid: state.city.uid,
    date: state.city.date,
    cities: state.city.cities,
    cityName: state.city.cityName
    //loading: state.city.loading
  };
};

//Make the component available to other parts of app
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { citiesShow, city, citiesToggle, getCity })(CityData);
```

CityReducer.js file

```js
import { MAIN_DATA, UPDATE_HOME, DATE, CITY_DATA, CITY_NAME} from '../actions/types';
import moment from 'moment';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    main: '',date: moment('01/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('DD MMMM YYYY'), cities: '', city: '',
    loading: false,
    selectedItem: ''
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_HOME:
            return { ...state, uid: action.payload };
        case CITY_DATA:
            return { ...state, cities: action.payload  };
        case CITY_NAME:
            return { ...state, city: action.payload };
        case MAIN_DATA:
            return { ...state, main: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;

    }
};
```

Comment: "I apply a condition to select another item in the list but after applying a condition in a program, a dialog box is not closing, it keeps remain on the screen with selected item's data in the background." Share this condition and also the actions that you are using to close the dialog.

Comment: @Anus Kaleem, in the render. I updated the code. I am not using any action to close the dialog box, but the state `slideAnimationDialog: false` in reducer

Comment: I suspect that you are not getting updated value of your props through reducers. Why are you not managing view property of dialog through your local state instead of redux state?

Comment: @Anus Kaleem, no I am getting the updated value of my props through reducer, which is displaying `slideAnimationDialog: false`, wait I am sharing console.log(this.props) screenshot here in a while